# Radius of Convergence for$S=\sum^{\infty}_{0}\frac{2^n(x-2)^n}{(n+2)!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Given $$S=\sum^{\infty}_{0}\frac{2^n(x-2)^n}{(n+2)!}$$

After using root test, I got,
$$-1\le\frac{2(x-2)}{(n+2)}\le 1$$
The n did not cancel. Now, How do I conclude about radius of convergence?

Thank You.

I did mistake, I used ratio test.

Comment: You need to take the limit $n\to\infty$ in order to apply the test.

Comment: It seems you applied the ratio test, not the root test.  Which is fine: take the limit as suggested.

Comment: yes. i did so. and got solution. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio test seems more suitable to me in this case:
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<1\implies\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n\text{ converges absolutely}$$
So in this case we have 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{2^{n+1}(x-2)^{n+1}}{(n+1+2)!}\frac{(n+2)!}{2^n(x-2)^n}\right|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{2(x-2)}{n+3}=0<1\quad \forall x\in \mathbb R$$
So the radius of convergence is .... (you should be able to fill it in now)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Radius of convergence= $1/\lim \sup_{n\to \infty }|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$ when the power series is $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$.